# Set row of JTable non-editable depending on contents

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I cannot find a solution for setting the cells of a row to non-editable depending on their contents.

There is a combobox in the first column of the `JTable` (called "CA") and a user can add more rows and choose the values they want. A new row can also be added to the "CA" `JTable` depending on changes in another `JTable`. When the new row is added it is given a specific value in its first column that does not exist in the combo box.

What I want is to make the whole row non-editable when this value appears in its first column.

I am familiar with the `isCellEditable` method, but I am not sure if it can be used for my "CA" `JTable's` model to determine if a cell will be editable or not depending on the 1st cow's value. I have also previously used the `prepareRenderer` method to set the background of a row depending on the values of the cells inside the `JTable`.

Is there any way of combining these 2 methods? If yes, how? If not, is there any other way? I would appreciate any suggestions.

This is where I create the "CA" JTable:

```
//create the List for the ComboBox
Strings createStrings = new Strings();
BillingAccountsCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
BillingAccountsCodes = createStrings.getBillingAccountsCodes();
BillingAccountsCodes.add(0, "Billing Accounts");

//create the combo box
BillingAccountsComboBox = new JComboBox();
for (int i=0; i<BillingAccountsCodes.size(); i++) {
    BillingAccountsComboBox.addItem(BillingAccountsCodes.get(i));
}
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(BillingAccountsComboBox);

//create the table's model
String[] columnTitles = {"Billing Account","Document","Billing Service","Notes","Quantity","Value","VAT %","Total"};
modelTableCA = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnTitles);

//set the model for the table and make the columns editable
tableCA = new JTable(modelTableCA){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        if (column == 7) { //I need this column to always be non-editable
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
};

tableCA.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);

//set the comboboxes to the columns
tableCA.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(BillingAccountsComboBox)); //billing acounts column
```

Solved it like this:

```
tableCA = new JTable(modelTableCA){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        if (tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("214") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("A00") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("A30") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("B00")) {
            if (column == 0 || column == 4 || column == 5 || column == 6 || column == 7) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (column == 7) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: `TableModel#isCellEditable(int, int)` is the method you want...it will give you chance to determine the cell contents and make your decisions

Comment: I have added the code where I create the "CA" JTable.  
@MadProgrammer How is it possible to decide if the row will be editable in this method by taking into account the contents of the 1st column?

Comment: You're in model. Use getValueAt to check the contents of what ever you want

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the answer, that's what I did I have added the code in my answer!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
tableCA = new JTable(modelTableCA){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        if (tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("214") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("A00") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("A30") || tableCA.getValueAt(row, 0).equals("B00")) {
            if (column == 0 || column == 4 || column == 5 || column == 6 || column == 7) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (column == 7) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```